# Writing Russian characters to txt file using python

Tags: python

I try to write to txt file list with russian string.(I get that with unique1 = np.unique(df['search_term']), it's numpy.ndarray)

```
thefile = open('search_term.txt', 'w')
for item in unique1:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

But in list this string looks correct. But after writing it looks like

```
 РїСЂРµРґРјРµС‚РѕРІ berger bg bg045-14 РѕС‚Р·С‹РІС‹
 Р·РІРµР·Рґ 
 РІРѕСЂРѕРЅРµР¶
```

Why a get that?

Comment: @Keiwan my list is `numpy.ndarray`  and I can't use this

Comment: What is the encoding of the data?

Comment: `utf-8` @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Does the data appear correct when you view it in your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to the file like this:

```
import codecs

thefile = codecs.open('search_term.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')  
for item in unique1:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

The problem is that the file likely is encoded correctly hence why the characters will display incorrectly.

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 2: invalid continuation byte`